# Limited "the_excerpt" text within a WordPress environment

Tags: php, wordpress

Through research, I've discovered this question has been asked on multiple occasions, however, my instance is a bit different.  I'm attempting to add a character limit to a pre-existing customer environment with the following elseif:

```
elseif(get_post_type() == 'post') {
    echo '<p class="excerpt">';
        the_excerpt();
    echo '</p>';
}
```

I attempted to use a couple of methods through functions, however, I've been unable to find a resolution.  I'm not natively a PHP developer, so I'm learning as I go here and hoping a fellow develop can help resolve this question and provide a brief description of how to handle this in the future.

Thanks!

**P.S. -** I read the documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags and wasn't able to make it work without breaking the rest of the else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_the_excerpt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) to return the text without printing it, and chop it to the length you want with [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```php
elseif(get_post_type() == 'post') {
    echo '<p class="excerpt">';

    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $limit = 100;
    if (strlen($excerpt) > $limit) {
        echo substr($excerpt, 0, $limit), '[...]';
    } else {
        echo $excerpt;
    }

    echo '</p>';
}
```

Comment: This worked great, now would there be a way of creating a [...] type of ending to the character limit? Meaning if it hits 100, could it then be followed up by [...] that doesn't need to be linkable, just a clear indicator that the character limit has been reached?

Comment: I've added some more code that checks the length and adds a `[...]` if it needs to be truncated

Comment: Would there be a way to prevent it from truncating in the middle of a word? If that is too complicated, I can revisit it another day.

Comment: I would do something like check if the character at `$limit` is a non-word character, and if not loop through the next characters until you find one.

Comment: Though another way would be to `preg_split` the excerpt at non-word characters, and construct the truncated excerpt from the array, checking the length as you add elements back into a string. So yea, definitely a more complex problem.

Answer (score 2):

By default, excerpt length is set to 55 words. To change excerpt length to 20 words using excerpt_length filter, add the following code to functions.php file in your theme:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this more. I forgot to mention the fact that I need it to have an end indicator, such as "..." or "[...]". How would I go about including that as well?

Comment: Just echo those characters after the excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this.

**Easy Way:**

Install the [Advanced Excerpt plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-excerpt/) and replace `the_excerpt();` with `the_advanced_excerpt()` and configure as needed in Settings -> Excerpt in admin panel (or use string query vars in the function call).  This also lets you do a lot of stuff like have custom "read more" link (or exclude it), add '...' or some other text at the end, strip or allow specific html tags, etc.

**Tedious Way:**

You can use `substr` PHP function ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)) in conjunction with `get_the_content();` or `get_the_excerpt()` to trim it to however many characters you want (or do whatever else you want to it) like freejosh's answer.

**Advanced / Clean Way:**

Filter the excerpt length to however many characters you want using the method described in Srikanth's answer (this is my preferred way, unless you need some of the Advanced Excerpt options like `use_words` etc).